# limit to addtobackstack for fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there any limit to number of fragments that can be added to an activity? limit in addtobackstack() of fragment. I googled it but I dint found anywhere mentioned regarding the limit.

Comment: I think there is no limit, but it's difficult to manage if you put a lot of fragments in backstack.

Answer (score 0):

So far, no limit for number of fragments in activity. And addToBackStack() is linked with FragmentTransaction